# Issue with JTextField and JComboBox in same GridBagLayout in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield, gridbaglayout

I am trying to get these two elements onto the frame using a GridBagLayout, but as soon as I add the JComboBox to the GridBagLayout and then add it to the frame, the JTextFields become very short in width and I have no idea why or how to fix it. When I take the JComboBox out, it works just fine, but I do need to have the JComboBox there, otherwise I can't complete the project. Any help on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code:

```
package userInterface;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class AddSpend extends JFrame {

    public AddSpend(){
        setTitle("Add New Spend");
        setSize(300,200);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        create();
    }

    private void create(){
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        add(new JLabel("Category: "), c);
        c.gridy++;
        add(new JLabel("Amount: "), c);
        c.gridy++;
        add(new JLabel("Date: "), c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        JComboBox<String> category = new JComboBox<String>();
        category.addItem("Test 1");
        category.addItem("Test 2");
        category.addItem("Test 3");
        add(category, c);
        c.gridy++;
        JTextField amount = new JTextField();
        add(amount, c);
        c.gridy++;
        JTextField date = new JTextField();
        add(date, c);
        c.gridy++;
        JButton today = new JButton("Today");
        today.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                date.setText((now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + now.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            }
        });
        today.setFont(today.getFont().deriveFont(7.0f));
        today.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30,15));
        add(today, c);
        c.gridy++;
        JButton add = new JButton("Add Spend");
        add(add, c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Suggestions:

- Get rid of `setSize(300,200);` and replace it with `pack();` By setting the size you artificially constrain your GUI to a certain size that likely is not the best natural size of it. By calling `pack()` after adding all components to the GUI, allow each component to size itself to its own calculated best size.
- Also, change `new JTextField();` to `new JTextField(col_width);` where col_width is an int that is the number of text columns you wish the JTextField to show. This will suggest to the JTextField to increase its preferred size to accommodate col_width number of characters.
- Also add insets to your GridBagConstraints
- Call `pack()` and `setVisible(true)` only **after** adding all components to the GUI and not before.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class AddSpend extends JPanel {

    public AddSpend() {
        create();
    }

    private void create() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        int ins = 5;
        c.insets = new Insets(ins, ins, ins, ins);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(ins, ins, ins, ins));

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        add(new JLabel("Category: "), c);
        c.gridy++;
        add(new JLabel("Amount: "), c);
        c.gridy++;
        add(new JLabel("Date: "), c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        JComboBox<String> category = new JComboBox<String>();
        category.addItem("Test 1");
        category.addItem("Test 2");
        category.addItem("Test 3");
        add(category, c);
        c.gridy++;
        JTextField amount = new JTextField(10);
        add(amount, c);
        c.gridy++;
        JTextField date = new JTextField(10);
        add(date, c);
        c.gridy++;
        JButton today = new JButton("Today");
        today.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                date.setText((now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + now.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            }
        });
        today.setFont(today.getFont().deriveFont(7.0f));
        today.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 15));
        add(today, c);
        c.gridy++;
        JButton add = new JButton("Add Spend");
        add(add, c);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Add New Spend");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new AddSpend());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Note that I much prefer to extending JPanel over JFrame. You may be painting yourself in a corner by having your class extend JFrame, forcing you to create and display JFrames, when often more flexibility is called for. In fact, I would venture that most of the Swing GUI code that I've created and that I've seen does **not** extend JFrame, and in fact it is rare that you'll ever want to do this. More commonly your GUI classes will be geared towards creating JPanels, which can then be placed into JFrames or JDialogs, or JTabbedPanes, or swapped via CardLayouts, wherever needed. This will greatly increase the flexibility of your GUI coding.